# How do I make it so that answers to requests in a form show in the URL once submitted?

Tags: forms, methods, get, submit, action

I am using VS code and a live server on my 127.0.0.1:5500  to visualize the code for me.
After filling out the form properly and pressing the submit button, I do not see the url change. I also do not see a message if I do not fill in all required inputs.

Begins like this after:

```html
<body>
    <h1> <u> Request a Quote</u></h1>
    <form action="." method="GET" >
        <div class="form-row">
            <label> 
                First name:
                <input type=text name="first-name" required >     
            <label>
```

And end like this:

```html
 <div class="form-row">
     <button type="button" id="Submit"> Send </button>
     <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
 </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to figure out if it was the form action and method. I do not quite know how I should write that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect that when you click *send* and *Mike* is in the input, the URL will be like this: http://127.0.0.1:5500/?first-name=Mike

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> <u> Request a Quote</u></h1>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5500/" method="GET" >
                <label> 
                    First name:
                </label>
                    <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name">

                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('first-name').value=''">

        </from>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perhaps this is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes I believe. Although I am not sure about the exact way it will show in the url, first name and mike will be on the right side of it \

Comment: onclick="document.getElementById('first-name').value=''">

What does this part of the code mean?

Comment: onclick - This attributes adds a click event handler to the element. When the element is clicked, the code in the value will execute.

Comment: document.getElementById('first-name') - This gets  the input field with id="first-name"

Comment: .value="" - This sets the value to an empty string, effectively clearing it

Comment: This is a JavaScript code that clears the value of an input field with id="first-name" when clicked. If this truly helped you, give me a vote plz :)